# how to organize class in a robotium project?

Tags: android, robotium

I have an activity A that launch an activity B.

I'd like to have a robotium project to test my app so I'v created a first test class for activity A and all goes well.

I'd like now to create another test class for testing Activity B but it require some init from activity A.

I tried this:

```
BTestClass extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    private Solo solo;
private ATestClass testA;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        Log.i(TAG, "setUp");

        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
        testA = new ATestClass();
        testA.setUp();
        testA.testAddAccount();
        solo.clickInList(0);
    }

    [… more test method]
}
```

I got a NullPointerException when testA is doing getActivity()

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

```
public class BTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SplashScreenActivity> {

    protected static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_ID = "app.under.test";

    protected Solo solo;

    public BTest() {
        super(TARGET_PACKAGE_ID, StartingActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        super.setUp();

        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());

        // setup stuff


    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {

        // teardown stuff


        super.tearDown();
    }

}
```

All testcases just inherit from BTest then

```
public class OneTest extends BTest {

    public void test_OneTest() {

        //test stuff
        solo.clickOnButton("Ok");

    }


}
```